# How to position a modal within a css grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My project's landing page has a modal that appears on a button click.  It was originally positioned using position: fixed and margins set to zero; in that way, it appeared basically at the center of the screen.

Now I want to position it using css grid because the landing page is a grid layout.  Here's the layout:

```
.grid {
display: grid;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 5%);
grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 5%);
}
```

In a separate css file, I have the css for the modal window.

```
.modalWindow {
display: grid;
grid-column: 8 / 15;
grid-row: 6 / 19;
position: fixed;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

But now, instead of appearing where I placed it in the grid (centered on the screen), it appears flush left and about one inch below the top of the browser window.

How do I change this css to properly position the modal within the grid?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also note that a grid container's absolutely-positioned children (this includes `position: fixed`), are removed from grid layout. They don't accept grid properties. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#static-position